# Add background color on drop event in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Select subject from the list than drop in fullcalendar the color that is define in attribute not show in calendar default color show.

I want to change the background color dynamically.But problem is if i hardcode the color name in eventColor than its work.if i store the color name in variable and than assign to eventColor its not work.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/david1212/paj0894s/5)

```
//Its not working
myColor = $(this).data("color"); //pick the color   
eventColor:myColor

//Its work  
eventColor:red
```

`

```
var myColor;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: true,
droppable: true,  
dragRevertDuration: 0,
drop: function() {

  if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {

    $(this).remove();
  }
  myColor = $(this).data("color");

},
eventColor:"red",
eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {

  if (isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
    var el = $("<div class='' data-color='"+myColor+"' >").css({'background-color':+myColor}).appendTo('#external-events-listing').text(event.title);
    el.draggable({
      zIndex: 999,
      revert: true,
      revertDuration: 0
    });
    el.data('event', {
      title: event.title,
      id: event.id,
      stick: true
    });
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eventColor:myColor
```

is a setup option. It is used once when the calendar loads - you give the value to fullCalendar, it accepts and sets up the calendar with that data. It isn't used again after that.

If you want to give an external event some custom data which will get used when the event is added to the calendar, you can do it when you initialise the custom events, by adding it to the list of event properties that the item has:

```
$(this).data('event', {
  title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
  stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
  color: $(this).data("color") // <-- get the colour from the data-attribute of the event
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c4woLm35/

Comment: Problem is when i first time drag the event to fullcalendar its work fine.But when i drop the event to draggable event all the settings removed.

Comment: "drop the event to draggable"...I have no idea what you mean by this? Did you try the demo? What exactly do you think is wrong with it? Please describe the exact steps to reproduce whatever problem you are trying to tell me about. The demo does exactly what you asked - when you drop the event on the calendar it shows up in the right colour. If you have a separate problem with another part of the code then accept this answer and ask a new question about that.

Comment: I tried the demo. its works correct. But when i drop the event in the list again all setting gone.

Comment: It's a typo: `.css({'background-color':+event.color})` should not have the `+`. http://jsfiddle.net/c4woLm35/1/

Comment: Thanks for your response but i don't no whats wrong with this fullcalendar setting if you drag and drop event 2 to 3 times setting still gone. Setting only works for the first time. :(

Comment: well, think about it logically...when you create the new "data" object to add to your new external element...are you putting in the color parameter, just like I showed above, or not? Do you think it should guess? Sorry I didn't bother mentioning that because I assumed it would be trivially obvious that you needed to put the exact same data back again as was there when you started.